# Confused on HTML for Mongo/Mongoose pagination

Tags: forms, express, pagination, mongoose

I currently have a collection with about 4,000 documents. I want to be able to paginate the results so users can only view 100 at a time.

I pretty much understand what to do on the server side when the search is submitted:

```
app.post('/browse/:page', function(req, res) {
    var page = parseInt(req.params.page);
    data = {};
    data.page = page;
    data.nextpage = page + 1;
    data.prevpage = page - 1;

    var filterOptions = _.transform(req.body, function(result, value, key) {
        result[key] = new RegExp(value.replace(/[^A-Za-z 0-9!'-]/g,''), "i");
    });

    Model.find(filterOptions).sort('brand').skip((page-1)*100).limit(100).exec(function(err, results) {
        //do stuff here with results
        res.render('browse.ejs', data);
    })
})
```

});

Now, on my view page this is what I have and where I think I am going about something quite wrong:

```
//header here

<div class="wrapper row2">
    <div id="container" class="clear">
    <section>
        <div id="browse-wrap">
            <div id="browse-left_col">
                <h3>Browse by:</h3><br>
                <form action="browse/1" method="post">
                    //form inputs and such here
                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Browse">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="browse-right_col">
                //table of results here
                <p style="text-align:right;"><a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].attr('action', 'browse/<%=nextpage%>').submit();return false;">Next 100 &#8594;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </div>
</div>

//footer here
```

Thanks for any help! I'm really new at this and appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things I'd suggest:

1. Use app.get() instead of app.post(). You're retrieving information from the server and the app.get() method represents a HTTP GET, which in turn represents retrieval. The app.post() method as you know represents a HTTP POST, which should be used for adding information to the server.
2. Once you use app.get() you can represent the pages on the client as simple links to /browse/:page
3. Be mindful of edge cases where page=0, page=last. You probably don't want to show a link to previous when there's no previous page.
4. Using skip() has performance penalties when you skip over large number of documents. Just something to keep in mind.

Server:

```
app.get('/browse/:page', function(req, res) {
        ...
        Model.find().sort('brand').skip((page-1)*100).limit(100).exec(function(err, results) {
           res.render('browse.ejs', {data:data, results:results});
        });
})
```

Client (using ejs as in your example):

```
// list data
<ul>
<% for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {%>
   <li><%= results[i]._id %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
// show prev/next page links
<a href="/browse/<%= data.prevPage%>">previous</a>
<a href="/browse/<%= data.nextPage%>">next</a>
```

Hope that helps.